# Mat date range date picker displays the wrong value - Angular

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

[image]

Mat date range date picker displays the wrong value

I need the start value 2021-02-01T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: share your implemented code here then only we will able to answer your query

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/dmojaobybmm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-forms-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

By default datepicker works with your local time (probably your time is  +5.30 ). Need to provide:

```
 { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true }},
```

If you want to work with UTC dates by default.